# does postive pole be a magnet to -e so that it would stick to it?

Tags: education

I've been wondering  in case -e electrons are attrcted to postive pole ?! Does this mean like it acts as a magnet and my question is if a beam of electrons is passing does it stops when it meets an anode opened at its center .. i know it will continue to flow but why does it continue to flow if it is just attracted to the  postive pole ..like what is making it continue to flow .. similarly in CRT

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part first, a voltage difference between two poles creates an electric field. Charged particles feel a force in an electric field and are therefore accelerated towards one of the poles ($e^-$ towards the positive pole, positive ions for example towards the negative pole).

You can imagine such a ciruit as a plate capacitor: as soon as enough electrons have flown onto the plates, the current stops and the potentials are the same. In an CRT, you keep the voltage drop between cathode and anode constant with a power supply, so no matter how many electrons hit the anode, the electric field stays the same and other electrons will still be accelerated. Basically, the power supply is like a pump that constantly gets rid of the electrons on the anode and pumps them back to the cathode. That costs energy of course, thats why you need energy to power a CRT, it doesn't run on its own.

This is so far nothing to do with magnets! The magnetic and electric field are similar and related,  but they are not identical. Rather, they are both aspects of the same thing. A resting electron (or any other charge) is not attracted to any pole of a magnet.

When things are in motion, that looks different: Using the Lorentz force law $$\vec F = q ( \vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$$ you can see that in an electric field $\vec E$, the charge feels a force *in direction* of $\vec E$.
However in a magnetic field $\vec B$, the charge feels a force perpendicular to its velocity and the magnetic field! Using the right-hand rule, you can see that if a positive charge moves along the x-axis in a magnetic field that is oriented along the y-axis, it will feel a force along the z-axis, at right angles to $\vec v$ and $\vec B$. You end up with a circular, not a linearily accelerated path!

Another big difference between magnetic and electric fields is that there is (highly probably) *no* magnetic monopole, the analog of an electric charge. Magnets always come in dipols with both North and South pole, splitting them doesn't change that.

So, the positive pole attracts the electrons, but in a different way that a magnet does.